# ¿Cómo completar el combobox en formularios wpf?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

Estoy realizando un proyecto en c# con formularios wpf sin embargo al momento de rellenar el combobox me tope con un problema en windows forms se utiliza name_combobox.DataSource sin embargo esta directiva no existe en WPF  quisiera saber cual es el equivalente a continuacion dejo fragmentos del codigo para las tres capas (presentacion, negocios y datos)

capa de datos

```
public class CD_Proveedor
{
    private CD_ConexionBD con = new CD_ConexionBD();
    private SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
    private SqlDataReader leerfilas;

    public DataTable ListarProvincias () {

        DataTable TablaP = new DataTable();
        comando.Connection = con.AbrirConexion();
        comando.CommandText = "MostrarProvincias";
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        leerfilas = comando.ExecuteReader();
        TablaP.Load(leerfilas);
        leerfilas.Close();
        con.CerrarConexion();
        return TablaP;
    }

    
}
```

capa de negocios

```
public class CN_Proveedores
{
    private CD_Proveedor proveedor_cd = new CD_Proveedor();
    public DataTable mostrarProvincias() {
        DataTable tablaProvincias = new DataTable();
        tablaProvincias = proveedor_cd.ListarProvincias();
        return tablaProvincias;
        
    }

   

}
```

capa de presentacion

```
 public FRM_Administracion_Proveedores()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListarProvincia();
     
    }
   
    private void btn_Regresar_P_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        FRM_Control_P paginaanteriorP = new FRM_Control_P();
        paginaanteriorP.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }

    public void ListarProvincia() {
        CN_Proveedores objCNPro = new CN_Proveedores();
        cmb_Provincia.DataContext = objCNPro.mostrarProvincias() ;
        this.cmb_Provincia.DisplayMemberPath = "NombreProvincia";
        this.cmb_Provincia.SelectedValuePath = "idProvincia";
        
    }
```

en la opcion provincia no aparecen las opciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El titulo tambien!!!

Comment: ItemsSource? sera lo que estas buscando?

Comment: no se como usar el itemsource lo que quisiera es que se pueda visualizar todas las opciones que estoy guardando en tabla de sql provincia  por que intente con datacontext y no funciono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cargar un DataTable en tu ComboBox desde un DataTable es necesario convertir las filas resultantes a una colección de objetos, para la cual yo utilizo la clase modelo Provincia.

Utilizo parte de tu código para el ejemplo:

```
    public void ListarProvincia() {
        CN_Proveedores objCNPro = new CN_Proveedores();
        //hago una llamada al método GetProvincias
        cmb_Provincia.ItemsSource = objCNPro.GetProvincias() ;
        this.cmb_Provincia.DisplayMemberPath = "NombreProvincia";
        this.cmb_Provincia.SelectedValuePath = "idProvincia";
        
    }
```

En caso de que te aparezca un error en la clase ObservableCollection
añade este using a tu clase `using System.Collections.ObjectModel`;

```
//Este método debes colocarlo dentro de tu clase en tu capa de negocios CN_Proveedores

    public ObservableCollection<Provincia> GetProvincias()
    {
         ObservableCollection<Provincia> provincias = new ObservableCollection<Provincia>();

         foreach (DataRow item in MostrarProvincias().Rows)
         {
             var provincia = new Provincia
             {
                 Id = int.Parse(item["idProvincia"].ToString()),
                 Nombre = item["NombreProvincia"].ToString(),
                 Ubicacion = item["UbicacionProvincia"].ToString()
             };

             provincias.Add(provincia);
         }

         return provincias;
    }
```

En una clase aparte puedes abstraer los campos de tu objeto provincia, para efectos de demostrar el ejemplo adicioné un campo ubicación:

```
public class Provincia
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Ubicacion { get; set; }

}
```

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.

Comment: Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado suprimido
Error CS0266 No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Data.DataTable' en 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. Ya existe una conversión explícita (compruebe si le falta una conversión) Formulario_Productos_ONG

Comment: Ya intente de esa manera pero me salia error

Comment: lo corrijo enseguida

Comment: Considera explicar tu solución, recuerda que no sólo es para quien pregunta sino para cualquier otra persona que tenga el mismo problema o uno similar. Por favor leer [answer]. Saludos

Comment: mi solucion para reemplazar el datasource de windows forms era utilizar el datacontext pero no me salen las opciones que tengo almacenadas en la tabla de sql server en el combo box

Comment: Gracias si me funciono pero se presento un problema el ListarProvincia en que funcion deberia agregar para que me cargue las opciones debido a que en el combobox carga pero no se puede visualizar el texto

Comment: qué problema se presentó? Revisa bien el método ListarProvincias en mi respuesta

Comment: ya lo corregi para que se vea ya en el formulario en listarProvincia  hay que cambiar los parametros NombreProvincia y idProvincia por Nombre y Id